# Visual Studio Code ignoring breakpoints

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have the python extension installed, I have ran python files and now I am trying to use the debugger but it skips my breakpoint and runs to the end of the file.

Here's the launch.json, for the most part, I use the current file python debug config it makes for me, I added the stop on entry part to see if it would change anything(it did not).

```
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal"
        }
        
    ],
    "stopOnEntry": true
}
```

and the code I'm testing the debugger on.

```
def swap(x, y):
    temp = x
    x = y
    y = temp
    return x,y
x = 2
y = 5

print(x)
print(y)
print("----2---") #break point here
x,y = swap(x, y) #break point here
print(x)
print(y)
```

Not sure What I"m doing wrong, or if I have the debugger set up incorrectly.

Comment: I have added the really simple code to the post, that I'm trying to test the debugger on. I'll admit I'm new to python but I don't think I have any flow control things that would stop it from reaching the breakpoint.

Comment: Do you use the debug mode to run your code, not the green play button on the top right.

Comment: Yeah, I click the debug icon, select the python config, and hit the button on the left next to the config option, the debug tool bar at the top briefly pop up but then the program finishes running and they disappear, all the while ignoring my breakpoints.,

Comment: try add `"justMyCode": false` and `"stopOnEntry": true` to launch.json,after `"console": "integratedTerminal"`,not outside.

Comment: `def swap(x,y): return y,x`

Comment: No dice on the justmycode & stoponentry changes.

Comment: @bryan -Since the debugging function of python code in VS Code is provided by the "Python" extension, please try to reinstall the "Python" extension. In addition, you could refer to this document to check the configuration of the debug file "launch.json": [Python debug configurations in Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging)